# To grep for a particular string in the first column of a text file in shell/linux

Tags: linux, shell

To grep for a particular string in the first column of a text file in shell.

I have text file which contains output as below:

```
29913  20   0 13164 5100 1060 S 34.1  0.0   0:00.18 option        
32725 20   0  9408  948  588 S 18.9  0.0   1231:22 option1        
30168 20   0 12532 4588 1056 S 13.3  0.0   0:00.07 option2        
 9963 20   0 38912 2088  648 S  7.6  0.0  25:48.13 option2
```

I would like to grep a string "9963" only in the first column of the text file, as there are chances of finding the same number in other columns of the file as well. After grepping for that particular string, I want the whole line to be printed as an output.

The output should be:

```
9963 20   0 38912 2088  648 S  7.6  0.0  25:48.13 option2
```

Please help me achieving this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use a "^" to anchor your search string, eg.

```
grep "^9963" input.txt
```

or explicitly only check first column with awk,

```
awk '$1 ~ /9963/' input.txt
```

For exact matches you could use `$1 == 9963` instead.

Comment: Thanks, but I have to make a variable replacement which is not happening inside awk. For example I am reading the string from a variable which is from other file....b=`awk -F'=' '{print $4}' file.txt and this wont work awk '$1 ~ /$b/' input.txt

Comment: to use awk with a variable use the `-v` flag (you could also use different quoting), eg. `awk -vstr="9963" '$1 == str' test.txt`

Answer (score 0):

`awk` also provides a trivial method of identifying the records wanted (and you have the full power of `awk` to the do any additional manipulations required), e.g.

```
$ awk '/^9963/' file
9963 20 0 38912 2088 648 S 7.6 0.0 25:48.13 option2
```

Above you simply search for the record matching `^9963` and rely on the default print operation to output the line from the file.

**Using a Shell Variable in `awk`**

You can use a shell variable in `awk` by making it an `awk` variable at the beginning using the `-v var=value` option (or within the `BEGIN{...}` rule). You can't use the variable as part of a regex, but you can compare against the first of the string using the `==` operator and the `substr` and `length` functions, e.g.

```
$ b=9963; awk -v b="$b" 'b == substr($1,1,length(b))'
9963 20 0 38912 2088 648 S 7.6 0.0 25:48.13 option2
```

Comment: How to make a variable replacement in awk?  For ex: awk '/^$b/' file